# error file creation failed - Upload JSON

Tags: java, android, json, upload, httpclient

Hi im trying to upload a file to a server. The way its done is likes this:
1. get upload url, by calling a JSON url
2. upload to the uploadUrl
3. get response

The documentation on the api call:

```
/file/uploadUrl

{ error: "", uploadUrl: <string>, progressUrl: <string> }

The returned URL is valid for a limited amount of time, you need to request a new one for each upload.
Issue a POST request to the "uploadUrl" to upload the file. You can poll "progressUrl" to fetch the current progress.
The POST request needs to be multipart/form-data encoded and contain a "file" field.
cUrl example: curl -F "file=@somefile.rar" "http://s6.baycdn.com/upload/93b37e57/4e691e0c/6/0?X-Progress-ID=4e639fcd34CC2F73796CF81679C605643A8F99CF"
Note: in order to upload a file to your account, you need to first log in using /account/login and then append ?session=XYZ to /file/uploadUrl
On success, the "uploadUrl" will respond with an object:
{ error: "", fileId: <string>, size: <int>, sha1: <string>, infoToken: <string>, deleteToken: <string>, linksUrl: <string>, downloadUrl: <string>, deleteUrl: <string>, }
```

The code i have: (onClick)

```
case R.id.upload:
            asyncTask = new JsonAsync();
            asyncTask.setJsonListener(new JsonListener() {
                public void onObjectReturn(JSONObject object) {
                    handleJsonObject(object);
                }
            });
            asyncTask.execute("http://api.bayfiles.net/v1/file/uploadUrl?session=" + sessionId);
            return true;
```

handleJsonObject:

```
 private void handleJsonObject(JSONObject object) {

        try {
            sUpload = object.getString("uploadUrl");            
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //post request to send the video 

            File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File myDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "Download");

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(sUpload);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy);
            FileBody video_file1 = new FileBody(new File(myDir + "/test.txt"));
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("file=@test.txt", video_file1);                    
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            // DEBUG
            System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

            // DEBUG
            System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
            if (resEntity != null) {
              try {
                System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
            } catch (org.apache.http.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            } // end if
            if (resEntity != null) {
              try {
                resEntity.consumeContent( );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            } // end if

            httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data: " + e.toString());
            Crouton.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!", Style.ALERT).show();
        }
    }
```

The error i get from server (JSON) is: {"error": "file creation failes"}

And the logcat:

```
10-14 13:17:29.954: I/System.out(22705): executing request POST http://s5.baycdn.com/upload/199808fb/52615115/7/2084659?X-Progress-ID=525bd2d5566FC893A0505FABB493A4215C7EC3AF HTTP/1.1
10-14 13:17:31.125: I/System.out(22705): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10-14 13:17:31.125: I/System.out(22705): {"error":"file creation failed"}
```

Comment: It appears to be an internal error on the server side. Have you contacted the service provider with your request ? The error message is not very helpful.

Comment: Yes i've tried, but they dont respond :(

Comment: instead of System.out.println, you can use Log.d(tag,message) ...

Comment: Also, your file is "test.txt" but you seem to be trying to upload a video file ... Maybe the server is trying to read the video file to recode it and cannot since you're uploading a text file ? Just a thought ;)

Comment: Log.d gave the same message. Also, it should matter what i called the string "video_file1" its still just a file, and it isnt defined just to be a video file :)